# Unable to connect using SSH to the pushed MobileFirst container image on Bluemix

Tags: ssh, ibm-cloud

I have built an MF container image and pushed it. I have copied the file in (Mac) ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to mfpf-server/usr/ssh before building the image.

I am trying to connect using the command in Mac terminal:

ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa admin@public_ip

It says:
Permission denied (publickey).

Any idea? What is the user I shall use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is very probably related to the permissions of the pub key copied on the container or to the configuration of your key.

You could check the permissions of key copied on the container, sshd is really strict on permissions for the authorized_keys files: if authorized_keys is writable for anybody other than the user or can be made writable by anybody other than the user, sshd will refuse to authenticate (unless sshd is configured with StrictModes no)
Moreover such a problem won't be showed using ssh -v, it will showed only on daemon logs (on the container)

From man sshd(8):

~/.ssh/authorized_keys
         Lists the public keys (RSA/DSA) that can be used for logging in
         as this user.  The format of this file is described above.  The
         content of the file is not highly sensitive, but the recommended
         permissions are read/write for the user, and not accessible by
         others.

```
     If this file, the ~/.ssh directory, or the user's home directory
     are writable by other users, then the file could be modified or
     replaced by unauthorized users.  In this case, sshd will not
     allow it to be used unless the StrictModes option has been set to
     “no”.
```

So I suggest you to check about the files and directories permissions.
Then check that the content of your pub key has been copied correctly on authorized_keys listing

/root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: I did set the permission to 0777 and used root@ip. Now it works. Thank you very much @v.bontempi

Answer (score 0):

To access the container with the ssh key you need to use the "root" user.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@<ip address>
```